# Orientation change crashes app on iOS 7 when using iAd (unrecognized selector sent to instance)

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins, iad

After integrating iAd, our app crashes whenever there is an orientation change (even though we lock the orientation to only portrait). We're on PhoneGap 3.2. Here is the output in Xcode:

```
2013-12-01 13:22:40.906 Wopple[4600:60b] -[CDViAd deviceOrientationChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x166b07e0
2013-12-01 13:22:40.907 Wopple[4600:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CDViAd deviceOrientationChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x166b07e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2df75e83 0x382d66c7 0x2df797b7 0x2df780af 0x2dec6dc8 0x2df37e71 0x2deabab1 0x2e891ec5 0x306ffca5 0x306ff2e9 0x306fecfd 0x30764321 0x32bde76d 0x32bde357 0x2df40777 0x2df40713 0x2df3eedf 0x2dea9471 0x2dea9253 0x32bdd2eb 0x3075e845 0xe1e63 0x387cfab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here is our iAd code:

```
//
//  CDViAd.m
//  Ad Plugin for PhoneGap
//
//  Created by shazron on 10-07-12.
//  Copyright 2010 Shazron Abdullah. All rights reserved.
//  Cordova v1.5.0 Support added 2012 @RandyMcMillan
//  Cordova v3.0.0 Support added 2013 @LimingXie

#import "CDViAd.h"
#import <Cordova/CDVDebug.h>


@interface CDViAd()

- (void) __prepare:(BOOL)atTop;
- (void) __showAd:(BOOL)show;

@end


@implementation CDViAd

@synthesize adView;
@synthesize bannerIsVisible, bannerIsInitialized, bannerAtTop, isLandscape;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Public Methods

- (CDVPlugin *)initWithWebView:(UIWebView *)theWebView {
  self = (CDViAd *)[super initWithWebView:theWebView];
  if (self) {
    // These notifications are required for re-placing the ad on orientation
    // changes. Start listening for notifications here since we need to
    // translate the Smart Banner constants according to the orientation.
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(deviceOrientationChange:)
               name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
             object:nil];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void) createBannerView:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult;
    NSString *callbackId = command.callbackId;
    NSArray* arguments = command.arguments;

    NSUInteger argc = [arguments count];
    if (argc > 1) {
        return;
    }

    BOOL atTop = NO;
    NSString* atTopValue = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    if( atTopValue ) atTop = [atTopValue boolValue];
    [self __prepare:atTop];

    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:callbackId];
}

- (void) showAd:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult;
    NSString *callbackId = command.callbackId;
    NSArray* arguments = command.arguments;

    NSUInteger argc = [arguments count];
    if (argc > 1) {
        return;
    }

    BOOL show = YES;
    NSString* showValue = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    if( showValue ) show = [showValue boolValue];
    [self __showAd:show];

    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:callbackId];
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    Class adBannerViewClass = NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView");
    if (adBannerViewClass && self.adView) {

        if( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( toInterfaceOrientation ) ) {
            self.isLandscape = YES;
            self.adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
        } else {
            self.adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
        }

        [self resizeViews];
    }
}

- (void) resizeViews
{
    Class adBannerViewClass = NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView");
    if (adBannerViewClass && self.adView) {

        CGRect webViewFrame = [super webView].frame;
        CGRect superViewFrame = [[super webView] superview].frame;
        CGRect adViewFrame = self.adView.frame;

        BOOL adIsShowing = [[[super webView] superview].subviews containsObject:self.adView];
        if (adIsShowing) {
            if (self.bannerAtTop) {
                webViewFrame.origin.y = adViewFrame.size.height;
            } else {
                webViewFrame.origin.y = 0;
                CGRect adViewFrame = self.adView.frame;
                CGRect superViewFrame = [[super webView] superview].frame;
                adViewFrame.origin.y = (self.isLandscape ? superViewFrame.size.width : superViewFrame.size.height) - adViewFrame.size.height;
                self.adView.frame = adViewFrame;
            }

            webViewFrame.size.height = self.isLandscape? (superViewFrame.size.width - adViewFrame.size.height) : (superViewFrame.size.height - adViewFrame.size.height);
        } else {
            webViewFrame.size = self.isLandscape? CGSizeMake(superViewFrame.size.height, superViewFrame.size.width) : superViewFrame.size;
            webViewFrame.origin = CGPointZero;
        }

        //[UIView beginAnimations:@"blah" context:NULL];
        //[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        //[self.adView setAlpha:1.0];
        //[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

        [super webView].frame = webViewFrame;

        //[UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Private Methods

- (void) __prepare:(BOOL)atTop
{
    NSLog(@"CDViAd Prepare Ad, bannerAtTop: %d", atTop);

    Class adBannerViewClass = NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView");
    if (adBannerViewClass && !self.adView) {
        self.adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
        self.adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, nil];        

        UIDeviceOrientation currentOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
        if( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( currentOrientation ) ) {
            self.isLandscape = YES;
            self.adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
        } else {
            self.isLandscape = NO;
            self.adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
        }

        self.adView.delegate = self;
        self.adView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        //[self.webView.superview addSubview:self.adView];

        self.webView.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        self.bannerAtTop = atTop;
        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
        self.bannerIsInitialized = YES;

        [self resizeViews];
    }
}

- (void) __showAd:(BOOL)show
{
    NSLog(@"CDViAd Show Ad: %d", show);

    if (!self.bannerIsInitialized){
        [self __prepare:NO];
    }

    if (!(NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView") && self.adView)) { // ad classes not available
        return;
    }

    if (show == self.bannerIsVisible) { // same state, nothing to do
        return;
    }

    if (show) {
        //[UIView beginAnimations:@"blah" context:NULL];
        //[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        //[self.adView setAlpha:1.0];
        //[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

        [[[super webView] superview] addSubview:self.adView];
        [[[super webView] superview] bringSubviewToFront:self.adView];
        [self resizeViews];

        //[UIView commitAnimations];

        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    } else {
        //[UIView beginAnimations:@"blah" context:NULL];
        //[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        //[self.adView setAlpha:0.0];
        //[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

        [self.adView removeFromSuperview];
        [self resizeViews];

        //[UIView commitAnimations];

        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma ADBannerViewDelegate

- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
    NSLog(@"Banner view begining action");

    [self writeJavascript:@"cordova.fireDocumentEvent('onClickAd');"];
    if (!willLeave) {

    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    NSLog(@"Banner view finished action");
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    NSLog(@"Banner Ad loaded");

    Class adBannerViewClass = NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView");
    if (adBannerViewClass) {
        if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {
            [self __showAd:YES];
        }

        [self writeJavascript:@"cordova.fireDocumentEvent('onReceiveAd');"];
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Banner failed to load Ad");

    Class adBannerViewClass = NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView");
    if (adBannerViewClass) {
        //if ( self.bannerIsVisible ) {
        //  [self __showAd:NO];
        //}

        NSString *jsString =
            @"cordova.fireDocumentEvent('onFailedToReceiveAd',"
            @"{ 'error': '%@' });";
        [self writeJavascript:[NSString stringWithFormat:jsString, [error description]]];
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        removeObserver:self
        name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
        object:nil];

    self.adView.delegate = nil;
    self.adView = nil;
}

@end
```

Edited code suggested by Rich Tolley:

```
- (CDVPlugin *)initWithWebView:(UIWebView *)theWebView {
  self = (CDViAd *)[super initWithWebView:theWebView];
  if (self) {
    // These notifications are required for re-placing the ad on orientation
    // changes. Start listening for notifications here since we need to
    // translate the Smart Banner constants according to the orientation.
    /*[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(deviceOrientationChange:)
               name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
             object:nil];*/
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    /*[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        removeObserver:self
        name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
        object:nil];*/

    self.adView.delegate = nil;
    self.adView = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the notifications because they are **device** orientation updates - rather than **interface** orientation updates. Even though the UI doesn't change orientation, the device can, so you still get updates.

The crash is because the code is missing the notification method:

`- (void)deviceOrientationChange:(NSNotification *)notification`.

Looking at the source of CDViAid.m, it subscribes to a notification but declares no method to handle it:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(deviceOrientationChange:)
           name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
         object:nil];
```

(There's nothing to deal with this on the superclass either)

There's a bug report for this at: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-iad/issues/1, and a suggested solution, which appears to duplicate `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`.

You could just remove the notification adding and removing code from `-init` and `-dealloc` - since it has no method to call, it can't be doing anything.

Comment: You're too awesome. Just to clarify, your suggestion is to, from the dealloc method,  comment out:   [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
  removeObserver:self
  name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
  object:nil];

Comment: And from the initWithWebView method, comment out: [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(deviceOrientationChange:)
               name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
             object:nil];

Comment: To make the formatting simpler, I updated the question with your proposed changes. Is that what you meant? Thanks again!